# Map different memories in standard C

Tags: c, testing, memory, standards, iar

I'm working developing some embedded system with an 8051 at work. Today, all codes are written with IAR, which manage the different memories of the micro with some keywords like __xdata, __pdata, etc...

We're starting with unit testing using the framework Ceedling and I think that the best way of testing my units is making a native executable (http://www.throwtheswitch.org/build/which) and test in my linux and then, once my soft is done, compile it for the 8051.

My problem now is that I don't know how to map the different types of memories of the micro without using the IAR keywords. Does anyone have this problem?

Comment: Too broad question. You can start looking [HERE](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_16.html) and  [HERE](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html)

Comment: I checked the first link, I don't know yet if my answer will be in the second link, but I noticed that an important details is missing in my problem description: all the memories of the microcontroller start in the 0x0000, I don't have an unique plain memory =S

Comment: https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F04x.pdf - page 133

Comment: Another important detail is that when compiling, IAR generates the ASM code according to the memory in which the data is alocated, 'cause in some cases it has to make some indirect calls via MOVX

Comment: I don't know about Ceedling framework. What I can say you is that the memory map of a MCU is very different from a complex CPU with MMU. Secondly IAR compiler isn't GCC and startup code, where bss and data sections are managed, is different.

Comment: Yes, I know, what IAR has the option for compiling according to the ANSI/C standard, so I thought of using that. I'm trying know of including the testing modules in a IAR project and see if I could work as ever...

Comment: I will comment about the results if I success

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the C pre-compiler to define a set of 'declaration' macros, although this could obfuscate the code making it more difficult to maintain.

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST
    #define DECLARE_DATA_VAR(type,name)   type __data name
#endif
```

Then you could define a similar macro for your unit test framework.  The following assumes GCC, so that an output section can be specified to the linker to represent `__data` variables.

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
    #define DECLARE_DATA_VAR(type,name)    type name __attribute__((section ("__data")))
#endif
```

Then in your code you would have to replace standard variable declarations using the macros.

```
 DECLARE_DATA_VAR(int,aNumber);
```

**Caveat:** If you do use the GCC `__attribute__` to place a variable in a named section you must be careful about the section attributes, as the `data` and `bss` sections have different attributes and you will not be able to mix them.  (Some architectures and compile tools have addition sections as well)!  For example, the following may not be mutually compatible;

```
DECLARE_DATA_VAR(int,aNumber);      // Will be placed in bss
DECLARE_DATA_VAR(int,aNumber) = 0;  // May end up in bss or data (it's up to the compiler implementation).
DECLARE_DATA_VAR(int,aNumber) = 1;  // Will be placed in data
```

**Alternative:**  You should consider very carefully exactly what you are 'unit testing'.  Think about encapsulating business functionality into functions that are independent of the underlying hardware implementation and providing a seperate hardware abstraction layer for all those parts that really do depend on the target and don't need to be unit tested (i.e. low level drivers).

You could end up writing your own 8051 simulator or spend more time abstracting your code for the sake of unit testing than you do adding business value to your software.